# This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it

Tags: web-services

I have deployed my webservice into Tomcat.
The WSDL has got some operations like ViewOptions, but when I ran that, I got this error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>1</faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Why do we get this error?

Answer (score 6):

The message isn't an "error" but rather a warning n need not be solved but ignored. An XML document is a data structure but does not contain any presentation/style information internally. Normally an XML document is used in inter-application communication or as a pure data structure that is then used with additional presentation/style information to display to users.

XML can be applied style by XSLT just as HTML by CSS and the above warning can be eradicated [An eg: of applying xls to xml](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog)

**We don't present xml using xls for RSS, Web Services as they are just used for communication without applying stylesheet rather than meant to be presented to user in browser.**

So, everything is fine here.

Comment: Change ur status line

Comment: broken link, fix it

Answer (score 0):

what worked for my case. I replaced all the links of `<a href=".."> ... </a>` with `window.open("...link", "_self")` and changed

```
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
} from 'react-router-dom';
```