# jquery webservice login

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, security

I've been trying to get this working for a good amount of time but I can't seem
to get my head around it.

I'm trying to login using jquery mobile calling an ASP.net webservice.
The webservice is working normally and can be used.
When using the debugger web page it results like this: (**true**)

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<boolean xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">true</boolean>
```

I don't believe there's something wrong with my service so here's my page code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="res/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="res/js/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="res/js/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost/as400/services.asmx/Login",
                        data: "{ user: " + $('#usr').val() + ", password: " + $('#psw').val() + "}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            alert(msg.d);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("error!");
                        }
                    });

            });
        });

    </script>

    <style>
      .ui-page { background: White;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="login">

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>Login</h1></div>

<div data-role="content">

    <img src="res/img/logo.gif" style="display: block;margin: 1em auto 0;width: 75%;" />

    <form id="login_form" name="login_form" data-ajax="false">
            <input type="text" name="usr" id="usr" value="" placeholder="user"/>
            <input type="password" name="psw" id="psw" value="" placeholder="password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit" name="login"/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" value="checked_remember"/>Remember me!</label>
        </form>

</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h2>Footer</h2></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Webservice code:

```
Imports connection

Imports System.Data

Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Script
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(Name:="services", ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class services
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Public connection As New connection

    <WebMethod()> _
    <SoapDocumentMethod(Binding:="services")> _
    <SoapHeader("connection")> _
    Public Function Execute(sql As String, type As Operation) As Result

        Dim r As New Result

        Select Case type
            Case Operation.SelectMultipleRows

                Try
                    r.Data = connection.Execute(sql, type)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    r.ErrorMessage = ex.Message
                    r.SQL = sql
                End Try

        End Select

        Return r

    End Function

    <WebMethod()> _
    <SoapDocumentMethod(Binding:="services")> _
    <SoapHeader("connection")> _
    Public Function Login(user As String, password As String) As Boolean

        Return connection.Login(user, password)

    End Function
End Class
```

I get an alert "error" but I don't know why...
I've put the webservice in debug and it runs through fine but it seems
like the jquery post is getting error before the service has being processed..?

Maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

Please help me!

Thx

Stanny

Comment: can we see the web service?

Comment: Can you tell us what version of jquery you are using?

Comment: included webservice code

Comment: using latest jquery 1.9.1

Comment: this may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551106/this-xml-file-does-not-appear-to-have-any-style-information-associated-with-it

Comment: @writeToBhuwan This is irrelevant, the style sheet for the response is optional.

Comment: Are you serving the page from the same hostname/port as you're sending the POST request to?

Comment: service is running localhost, page is virtual directory on same IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by myself by redesigning. Question is obsolete.