# python scripts to create a table on azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, raspberry-pi2

So I'm tryna run a python script that reads data from the Z wave sensors via the Rpi and using crontab on the pi I have set so the python script would run every minute and store it in a text file. Then I have another python script that sends the data to the azure cloud storage in a table form. The problem is that is does create a table but theres an error "**This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it**". Ive been trying to figure it out but nothing I can see is wrong.

This is the python script that sends data to the cloud

```
from azure.storage import TableService, Entity
from datetime import datetime
import socket

ac_name = 'account name'
#you will have to use your own azure account
primary_key = 'use your key'
table_name = 'Readings'

current_temperature = 0

def get_connection_string_and_create_table():
    global table_service
    table_service = TableService(account_name = ac_name,account_key=primary_key)
    #table_service.delete_table(table_name = table_name) #TO BE USED IF THE TABLE NEEDS TO BE DELETED
    table_service.create_table(table=table_name)

def insert_data():
    reading = create_entity()
    try:
        if check_internet_available():
            table_service.insert_entity(table_name = table_name,entity = reading)
            return True
    except Exception, e:
        return False


def create_entity():

    """
    -   Creates the data block that would be sent to the cloud, named as Entity
    """

    time_now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    print('Date time is {0}'.format(time_now))
    reading = Entity()
    reading.PartitionKey = 'Room1'
    reading.RowKey = time_now
    reading.Timestamp = datetime.now()
    reading.Temperature = str(current_temperature)
    return reading

def initialize_azure():
    get_connection_string_and_create_table()

def send_data_to_cloud(temperature):
    global current_temperature
    current_temperature = temperature
    sent_success = insert_data()
    print temperature
    print sent_success
    return sent_success


def check_internet_available():

    """
    -   Checks internet availability, the data will be sent to cloud
        only if there is an active internet connection

         remote_server = 'www.google.com'
    try:
        host = socket.gethostbyname(remote_server)
        s = socket.create_connection((host,80),2)
        return True
    except:
        pass
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':

    get_connection_string_and_create_table()
    f = open('Meter.txt', 'r')
    send_data_to_cloud(f.readline())
```

And this is the script that reads the data via HTTP requests from an API

```
import urllib2
import json
import requests
import time
import json

class EnergyConsumptionControl:

    # Class constructor
    def __init__(self):
        # Global Variables
        self.energyMeterDeviceUrl = "http://IpaddressofyourRpi"
        self.session = requests.Session()
        # Logging in
        self.Login()


    def ActivateDevice(self, deviceID):
        energyMeterDeviceSwitchOn = ":8083/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[" +  str(deviceID)  + "].SwitchBinary.Set(255)"
        response = self.SendGetCommand(energyMeterDeviceSwitchOn)  # Command to turn device on
        return [response]


    def DeactivateDevice(self, deviceID):
        energyMeterDeviceSwitchOff = ":8083/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[" + str(deviceID)  + "].SwitchBinary.Set(0)"
        response = self.SendGetCommand(energyMeterDeviceSwitchOff)  # Command to turn device off
        return [response]


    def GetDeviceState(self,  deviceID):
        # Call the Get() function to update the SwitchBinary data
        energyMeterDeviceSwitchGet = ":8083/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[" + str(deviceID) + "].SwitchBinary.Get()"
        response = self.SendGetCommand(energyMeterDeviceSwitchGet)
        # Call to return the SwitchBinary JSON object
        energyMeterDeviceSwitchGet = ":8083/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[" + str(deviceID) + "].SwitchBinary"
        response = self.SendGetDeviceStateCommand(energyMeterDeviceSwitchGet)
        return response


    # def GetDeviceMeter(self, deviceID):
    #     # Refreshing server-side information on the Meter through device interrogation
    #     energyMeterDeviceMeterGetVals = ":8083/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[" + str(deviceID) + "].Meter.Get()"
    #     response = self.SendGetCommand(energyMeterDeviceMeterGetVals)
    #     # Retrieving the JSON of all Meter related data
    #     energyMeterDeviceMeterGet = ":8083/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[" + str(deviceID) + "].Meter"
    #     response = self.GetMeterWattage(energyMeterDeviceMeterGet)
    #     return [response]

    def GetDeviceEnergyConsumption(self,  deviceID):
        # Refreshing server-side information on the Meter through device interrogation
        energyMeterDeviceMeterRefreshVals = ":8083/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[" + str(deviceID) + "].Meter"
        response = self.SendGetCommand(energyMeterDeviceMeterRefreshVals)

        # Retrieving the JSON of all Meter related data
        energyMeterDeviceMeterGetVals = ":8083/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[" + str(deviceID) + "].Meter"
        energyConsumption = self.GetMeterConsumption(energyMeterDeviceMeterGetVals)

        response = self.ResetDeviceMeter(deviceID)
        return energyConsumption
 def GetDeviceEnergyWattage(self,  deviceID):
        # Refreshing server-side information on the Meter through device interrogation
        energyMeterDeviceMeterRefreshVals = ":8083/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[" + str(deviceID) + "].Meter.Get()"
        response = self.SendGetCommand(energyMeterDeviceMeterRefreshVals)

        # Retrieving the JSON of all Meter related data
        energyMeterDeviceMeterGetVals = ":8083/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[" + str(deviceID) + "].Meter"
        energyWattage = self.GetMeterWattage(energyMeterDeviceMeterGetVals)
        print energyWattage
        return energyWattage


    def ResetDeviceMeter(self, deviceID):
        energyMeterDeviceMeterReset = ":8083/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[" + str(deviceID) + "].Meter.Reset(255)"
        response = self.SendPostCommand(energyMeterDeviceMeterReset)  # Command to reset device meter value
        return [response]


    def Login(self):
        data = {
            "form": True,
            "login": "admin",
            "password": "#password",
            "keepme": False,
            "default_ui": 1
        }

        # Authenticating
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        response = self.session.post(self.energyMeterDeviceUrl + ':8083/ZAutomation/api/v1/login', headers=headers,
                                data=json.dumps(data))

    # Generic function to send GET commands to individual Z-Wave devices
    def SendGetCommand(self, command):
        status = self.session.get(self.energyMeterDeviceUrl + command)
        print status
        print status.text
        return [status]

    # Generic function to send POST commands to individual Z-Wave devices
    def SendPostCommand(self, command):
        status = self.session.post(self.energyMeterDeviceUrl + command)
        print status
        print status.text
        return [status]

    def GetMeterWattage(self, command):
        status = self.session.get(self.energyMeterDeviceUrl + command)
        json_data = json.loads(status.text)
        # Parsing the JSON data to get just the energy wattage (W)
        return json_data['data']['2']['val']['value']


    def GetMeterConsumption(self, command):
        status = self.session.get(self.energyMeterDeviceUrl + command)
        json_data = json.loads(status.text)
        # Parsing the JSON data to get just the energy consumption (kWh)
        return json_data['data']['0']['val']['value']
 def SendGetDeviceStateCommand(self, command):
        status = self.session.get(self.energyMeterDeviceUrl + command)
        json_data = json.loads(status.text)
        # Parsing the JSON data to get just the 'level'
        return int(json_data['data']['level']['value'])


control = EnergyConsumptionControl()
response = control.GetDeviceEnergyConsumption(8)
print response


control = EnergyConsumptionControl()
response = control.ActivateDevice(8)
print response
```

Is there a way to either combine the two so that it calls the data and sends it to the cloud??
How can I fix the error Message

Comment: You could test your code separately to find where the problem in, uploading code or downloading code. You cloud see your download file content to inspect whether it's a standard XML file. This URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804452/opening-facelets-page-errors-with-this-xml-file-does-not-appear-to-have-any-sty may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when there is no presentation/style information present for rendering, and in this case it is an Xml for communication so probably not needed. Here is another related thread - this might help.

[This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551106/this-xml-file-does-not-appear-to-have-any-style-information-associated-with-it)